# Chrome拡張の公式サンプルでのjavascriptに関する不明点の質問

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Chrome拡張で公式のサンプルを見たところ不明点がありました。
自分では気がつけてないメリットがあるかもしれないので解説をお願いしたく質問します。

### 質問

後述のコードでchrome.bookmarks.getTreeをvar bookmarkTreeNodesでうけている理由はなんでしょうか？
別にchrome.bookmarks.getTreeのコールバックでfunction(bookmarkTreeNodes){}が実行されれば特に問題は無い認識です。
それにも関わらずなんのために戻り値を変数でうけているのでしょうか？

### 公式のサンプルの場所

- 下記URLのMy Bookmarks
  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples

### popup.js内の該当のコード

```
function dumpBookmarks(query) {
  var bookmarkTreeNodes = chrome.bookmarks.getTree(
    function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
      $('#bookmarks').append(dumpTreeNodes(bookmarkTreeNodes, query));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードの作者ではないので意図は理解できませんが、代入しなくても全く同じ動作となるので代入が無い方が混乱を招きにくいとは思います。